# Extracting first key by value in nested json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a json format from which I have to extract the key:value very first time it appears in the file. Went through several examples, but getting an error.

```
{
     "search-results": {
     "entry": [
        {
            "@_fa": "true",
            "eid": "10-s2.0-60103485",
            "prism:url": 
"https://api.elsevier.com/content/affiliation/affiliation_id/60103485"
        },
        {
            "@_fa": "true",
            "eid": "10-s2.0-113310784",
            "prism:url": 
"https://api.elsevier.com/content/affiliation/affiliation_id/113310784"
        },
```

I tried :

```
myvar = results['search-results'][0]['entry']['eid']
print (myvar)

TypeError: string indices must be integers


results = json.dumps(resp.json(),
             sort_keys=True,
             indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))


print(results)
myvar = results['search-results'][0]['entry']['eid']
print (myvar)
```

I need to extract `"eid": "10-s2.0-60103485"` the very first time it appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not quite clear about this point but if this :

```
results = json.dumps(resp.json(),
             sort_keys=True,
             indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))


print(results)
myvar = results['search-results'][0]['entry']['eid']
print (myvar)
```

is the code that raised the TypeError, then well, that's very obviously what one would expect. `json.dumps(obj, ...)` takes a Python object and serializes it to a json string, so in your code `results` IS a string (the fact that it contains json-formatted content is totally irrelevant). To deserialize a json string to Python (so you get a python object that you can use), you want `json.loads(somejsonstr)` instead.

Now actually, `resp.json()` (where I assume `resp` to come from the `python-requests` lib) already takes care of deserializing it's content to Python, so you don't have anything more to do - except, of course, getting the dict keys / list indexes in the right order as already mentionned by James_F:

```
resp = requests.get(someurl)
results = resp.json()
myvar = results['search-results']['entry'][0]['eid']
print(myvar)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer and especially for the explanation. I tried the same way before your answer and it worked, got a bit late to answer my won question. But that was I guess pure luck, now I can actually understand how it works.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to flip the positions of `['entry']` and `[0]`.

```
myvar = results['search-results']['entry'][0]['eid']
print (myvar)
```

Comment: I'm getting error `TypeError: string indices must be integers`.

Comment: Try Using json.dump() instead.

Comment: @K.S I am unable to reproduce the error. Is the data being successfully loaded? Are you able to print it? Because otherwise, I don't know how you could be getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try using jsonpath_ng.ext.

```
from jsonpath_ng.ext import parse

f = parse("$..entry[?(@.eid=='10-s2.0-60103485')]").find(data)
print(f[0].value)
```

This outputs `{'@_fa': 'true', 'eid': '10-s2.0-60103485', 'prism:url': 'https://api.elsevier.com/content/affiliation/affiliation_id/60103485'}`

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. While suggesting solutions based on 3rd part libs is ok (and a good idea when the lib is well maintained), it's better to first start with the stdlib/builtins base solution, specially for trivial tasks such as navigating dicts and lists. If your answer was intented as an addition to an already posted stdlib/builtins based solution, you should explicitely mention it (ie : "in addition to XXX solution which is the standard way, you can also use `somelib`: example code here").  Also your answer should include the url to the suggested lib's homepage.

Comment: @ bruno - Thanks for the hints. The url to jsonpath_ng is https://github.com/h2non/jsonpath-ng.